# auto save javascript with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I created a localstorage for the form on rails, when I tried the js code above for the
`<textarea id="text"></textarea>` tag it worked,
but when I tried the code like this, `<%= f.text_area :title, class:"quill_container", id:"text" %>`  it only managed to retrieve the key, the value couldn't be retrieved

javascript code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            if (localStorage) {
                var content = localStorage.getItem("autoSave");
                if(content) {
                    $('#text').text(content);
                }
            }
```